# Access Pass-Through Outer Apply

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, select, pass-through

I'm attempting to use an outer apply in an access pass-through query; however, it seems to have issues with the outer apply. The query is below. It runs fine in SQL Server directly, but when run as a pass-through query, I get a syntax error in the FROM clause.

The syntax error text is: "Syntax error in FROM clause"
The pass-through will run and produce data when I text run it; however, when I attempt to save it for the report, the validation issue occurs.

```
SELECT AccountNumber, ICN, Provider, RequestDate, patLast, patFirst
FROM tblracaccounts
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT TOP 1 patLast, patFirst FROM tblAccts WHERE LEFT(icn,14)=LEFT(tblracaccounts.ICN,14)
) t2
WHERE ICN NOT IN (SELECT ICN FROM tblracstatuses WHERE Cancelled=1 OR Findings='No Findings')
ORDER BY Provider, RequestDate DESC
```

Comment: Perhaps `LEFT(icn,14)` should be `LEFT(tblAccts.icn,14)`?  Otherwise, I'm thinking you need to verify that the query is actually pass-through, because as I'm sure you're aware, MS Access isn't supposed to validate on pass-through queries.

Comment: What is the text of a syntax error? When you remove the `APPLY` clause does it still happen?

Comment: @IvanG I've edited above for the text of the error. With the apply removed, there are no issues.

Comment: @coge.soft Yeah, that's what I thought. I tried the icn bit, but no dice. The pass-through will run in test using the run button, but will not save. It's a pass-through used in a report.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reports do not allow the outer apply as a pass-through query directly in the report. Moving the query to an access pass-through query and then referencing that query in the report works.